# Use 2 malloc calls to define 1 array c

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I am trying to make an unsigned char array in c++ that is ~ 4 gigabytes in size.

The code I am using to malloc the space for the array is below:

```
unsigned char *myArray= (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3774873600);
  if(myArray==NULL)
    {
      cout << "Error! memory could not be allocated. \n";
    }else{
      cout << "You allocated memory for myArray \n";
    }
```

When I run the program I get the success message saying that the memory was allocated. Then when I run:

```
myArray[0] = 20;
cout << myArray[0];
```

I get 20 as the answer.

However if I run:

```
myArray[3774873599] = 20;
cout << myArray[3774873599];
```

The program crashes.

I was thinking it is probably because the malloc call is asking for too much continuous memory in 1 call (4gb).

Perhaps it would be better to split the malloc call in 2 parts, and then join them together as 1 continuous array. Would that be possible?

Also in case you are wondering my computer has 64 gb of memory on a 64bit OS, and the program is compiled as 64bit, so I don't think it's at it's limits or anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `new` to allocate memory in C++.

Comment: Or better yet `std::vector<unsigned char> myArray(3774873600)`

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: @Rinat Veliakhmedov Using new worked! Wow thank you. What would make new work when malloc failed?

Comment: Perhaps you failed to include the header that declared `malloc`. Do you get warnings when you compile?

Comment: @MOehm I didn't know there was a header for malloc. No I don't get any warnings compiling. These are my headers: fstream, iostream, string, sstream, vector, math.h

Comment: If you get no warnings (with warnings enabled), then it's probably okay. `malloc` is defined in `<stdlib.h>` for C and (as `std::malloc`) in `<cstdlib>`. But the macro `NULL` is defined there, too, so I guess one of the other headers includes it.

Comment: Have you tried `3774873599LL`? or compile in C++11 mode.

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined as 1. You were probably trying to access myArray[negative number], although that is surprising if it was truly using 64bit int. But just because it can doesn't mean it will. Check sizeof(int).